# CSS fixed footer wide image center on resize

Tags: html, css, image, center, footer

I have a wide image I want to use as a fixed footer.  The main page is 960px and centered, and the footer is 1620px. If the browser window is greater than 960px wide, then it shows more and more of the footer image without displaying scroll bars.

How can I achieve this?  So far I have this, but it's wrong:

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -340px;
  text-align: center;
}

div#body-container {
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.footer, .push {
  width: 1620px;
  height: 340px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="body-container"> <!-- width: 960px -->
    <!-- content -->
  </div>

  <!-- fixed footer -->
  <div class="push"></div>
  <div class="footer"><img src="img/footer.png"></div> <!-- width: 1620px -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer {
width:100%;
height:345px;
display: block;
background:url(/img/footer.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by updating the width of your `footer` to `100%` and adding the property `overflow: hidden` which will remove the scrollbars if the content inside (the image) is larger than the width of the footer.

It gets a little more complicated however if what you're trying to do is also center the image. For this you'll need to add `relative` positioning to the `.footer` and `absolute` positioning to the `img`. You'll also need to add `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -810px` (half of your image width) to the img.

Here is the final updated portions of the code:

```
.footer, .push {
    width: 100%; /* changed from 1620px;*/
    height: 340px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.footer img {
    width: 1620px;
    height: 340px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -810px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/uf8Lh/